# Owl Carousel 2 width issue on browser scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel-2

I'm using Owl Carousel 2 with Bootstrap framework. There are 12 items that I have in the Carousel and I need to display three on the 1280-pixel wide resolution.

The `owl-stage` width is calculated as the total width of the Carousel (on desktop-1280px) which comes out to be as `3772px` when there is no scroll bar on page.

Now if I open developer tools and then close it back again (i.e. bring a scroll bar onto the page and then remove) the width of class `owl-stage` becomes `3840px`.

Due to this, on page load since the width is `3772` some content of the fourth slide is visible (probably just 5–6 pixels) but it disturbs the layout.

`autoWidth:true` is not applied.

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 0,
    nav: true,
    onInitialized: fixOwl,
    onRefreshed: fixOwl,
    navText: [
        "<span class='left-arrow-purple-bar'></span>",
        "<span class='right-arrow-purple-bar'></span>"
    ],
    responsiveClass: true,
    responsive: {
        320: {
            items: 1.2,
            nav: true
        },
        520: {
            items: 1.45,
            nav: true
        },
        720: {
            items: 2.4,
            nav: false
        },
        960: {
            items: 3,
            nav: true,
            loop: false,
            slideBy: 3,
            margin: 0
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It's unclear what the actual question is based on your description, which is a slight wall of text. Describe what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Comment: On page load,the width of 'owl-stage' class is 963px.In chrome the scrollbar width is 17px which is not added in the above width.Now if scrollbar appears and then goes(opening developer tools and docking to below) then the width of class 'owl-stage' becomes 980 which is expected on load.
I want the width of 'owl-stage' to be 980px on init itself rather than after scrollbar appearing and going.

Comment: Please update the body of the _question_ with details like this via the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46240929/edit) button.